# Calculation between columns (longitude/latitude) very slow

Tags: python, pandas, math, multiple-columns, latitude-longitude

I have two separate datasets,`df` and `df2`, each dataset has the columns `longitude` and `latitude`. What I am trying to do is find the point in `df` that is closest to the point in `df2`, and calculate the distance between them in `km` and append each value to a new column in `df2`.

I've come up with a solution, but keep in mind `df` has `+700,000` rows and `df2` has about `60,000` rows, so my solution will take way too long to compute. The only solution I could come up with is using a double `for` loop...

```
def compute_shortest_dist(df, df2):
    # array to store all closest distances
    shortest_dist = []

    # radius of earth (used for calculation)
    R = 6373.0
    for i in df2.index:
        # keeps track of current minimum distance
        min_dist = -1

        # latitude and longitude from df2
        lat1 = df2.ix[i]['Latitude']
        lon1 = df2.ix[i]['Longitude']

        for j in df.index:

            # the following is just the calculation necessary
            # to calculate the distance between each point in km
            lat2 = df.ix[j]['Latitude']
            lon2 = df.ix[j]['Longitude']
            dlon = lon2 - lon1
            dlat = lat2 - lat1
            a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2)**2
            c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
            distance = R * c

            # store new shortest distance
            if min_dist == -1 or distance > min_dist:
                min_dist = distance
        # append shortest distance to array
        shortest_dist.append(min_dist)
```

This function takes way too long to compute and I know there must be a more efficient way but I am not very good at `pandas` syntax.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: well it has to loop 42000 million times so I don't think there's a really efficient way to calculate that. You could try to use a module to parallelize the process to make it twice, four times as fast, but I can't think of a better way

Comment: The calculation of `numpy.ndarray` should be faster than that of `pandas.core.series.Series`. You may try adding `.values` when you extract the latitude and longitude.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7129482/1679849

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the inner loop in `numpy`, which should speed it up significantly:

```
import numpy as np

def compute_shortest_dist(df, df2):
    # array to store all closest distances
    shortest_dist = []

    # radius of earth (used for calculation)
    R = 6373.0
    lat1 = df['Latitude']
    lon1 = df['Longitude']
    for i in df2.index:
        # the following is just the calculation necessary
        # to calculate the distance between each point in km
        lat2 = df2.loc[i, 'Latitude']
        dlat = lat1 - lat2
        dlon = lon1 - df2.loc[i, 'Longitude']
        a = np.sin(dlat / 2)**2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(dlon / 2)**2
        distance = 2* R * np.arctan2(np.sqrt(a), np.sqrt(1 - a))

        # append shortest distance to array
        shortest_dist.append(distance.min())
    return shortest_dist
```

Comment: dont use `ix` because [deprecated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated), better is `df2.loc[i, 'Longitude']`